# Adding persistence to local storage to a Vue app

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am learning to deal with VueJS and made a simple todo app. It works well, but I want to store data locally and make it persistent even if there is a page reload.

This is the code produced following instruction of a few useful tutorials (leaving CSS outside to ease readability):

```
<template>
  <div class="main-container">
    <div class="header md-elevation-4">
      <h1 class="md-title">{{ header }}</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="todo-list">
      <div class="row"></div>
      <div class="row">
        <!-- add new todo with enter key -->
        <md-field class="todo-input">
          <md-input
            v-model="currentTodo"
            @keydown.enter="addTodo()"
            placeholder="Add a todo! It's easy!"
          />
        </md-field>
        <!-- for all todos, set class of edited todos -->
        <ul class="todos">
          <div class="list-div">
            <li v-for="todo in todos" :key="todo.id">
              <!-- binds checkbox to todo model after each instance; -->
              <input
                class="toggle-todo"
                type="checkbox"
                v-model="todo.completed"
              />
              <!-- starts editing process on double click -->
              <span
                class="todo-item-label"
                :class="{ completed: todo.completed }"
                @dblclick="editTodo(todo)"
                v-if="!todo.edit"
                >{{ todo.label }}</span
              >
              <!-- concludes editing with enter click -->
              <input
                v-else
                class="todo-item-edit"
                type="text"
                v-model="todo.label"
                @keyup.enter="completedEdit(todo)"
              />
              <!-- deletes todos using removeTodo method -->
              <i
                class="material-icons"
                alt="remove toDo"
                @click="removeTodo(todo)"
                >delete</i
              >
            </li>
          </div>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "RegularToolbar",
  data() {
    return {
      header: "A VueJS ToDo App",
      todos: [],
      currentTodo: "",
      completed: false, // add a completed property
      editedToDo: null // add a edited property
    };
  },
  methods: {
    addTodo() {
      this.todos.push({
        id: this.todos.length,
        label: this.currentTodo,
        completed: false, // initializes property
        edit: false // initializes property
      });
      this.currentTodo = "";
    },
    mounted() {
      // console.log('App mounted!');
      if (localStorage.getItem("todos"))
        this.todos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todos"));
    },
    watch: {
      todos: {
        handler() {
          // console.log('Todos changed!');
          localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(this.todos));
        },
        deep: true
      }
    },
    removeTodo(todo) {
      // allows users to remove todos
      var index = this.todos.indexOf(todo);
      this.todos.splice(index, 1);
    },
    editTodo(todo) {
      todo.edit = true;
    },
    completedEdit(todo) {
      todo.edit = false;
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped></style>
```

As it is, all the JS part referring to mount and watch does not work. I am able to add new todos and delete them as I wish, but it does not retain the data if the user reloads the page.

Could some of the colleagues spot what I am missing here?

Comment: It looks like some functions that should be `methods` are in the `watch` section of code. I'm still poking around, but that might solve some of your problems. Or it might be copy/paste errors. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a problem of code organization:

Your `mounted` and `watch` sections are currently inside the `methods` section, which will prevent them from firing as expected.

Move those out into their own sections (both should be at the same level as `methods`) and you should be all set.

With those edits and nothing else, I've got your code working in a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/ebbishop/dc82unyb/